# How can i display the first five lines that differ between 2 files, in a shell script?

Tags: arrays, linux, shell, file, ubuntu

I ve tried using 2 arrays to compare the 2 files, but i m a rookie and i don't know how to do it:

```
vec_fis_1=`cat fisier.txt`
vec_fis_2=`cat fisier1.txt`
echo $vec_fis_2
echo $vec_fis_1
for i in ${vec_fis_1[@]}
do
        for j in ${vec_fis_2[@]}
        do
                if ( "$i" == "$j" )
                then
                        echo $i
                        echo $j
                fi
        done
done
```

Comment: Check your scripts at https://shellcheck.net . Use `diff` with `head -n5`.

Comment: This command displays the first 5 lines from both files, but i only need the first 5 lines that differ from a file to another.

Comment: Are the files sorted?

Comment: No they are not.

Comment: So, easiest approach would probably be to first `sort` both files into temporary files, then `diff` them, as @KamilCuk alludes to. You would need to change the parms to `diff` or run the output from diff through `grep` or `awk` to allow for the various information lines produced by the `diff` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use backticks `. Use `$(..)` instead.

So instead of `if ( "$i" == "$j" )` do `if [ "$i" != "$j" ]`.

`vec_fis_1` and `vec_fis_2` are not arrays - `${vec_fis_1[@]}` is just same as `$vec_fis_1`.

To read a file into an array, use `readarray`.

To iterate over lines in file use a `while read loop`, see [bashfaq how to read a file line by line](https://www.google.com/search?channel=crow2&client=firefox-b-d&q=how+to+read+a+file+line+by+line+bashfaq).

```
while IFS= read -r l1; do
     while IFS= read -r l2; do
         if [ "$l1" != "$l2" ]; then
            printf "%s\n" "$l1"
            printf "%s\n" "$l2"
         fi
     done < fisier1.txt
done < fisier.txt
```

> i only need the differences between lines with the same "line index"

So read from both files at the same time.

```
while IFS= read -r -u3 l1 && 
         IFS= read -r -u4 l2; do
    if [ "$l1" != "$l2" ]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$l1"
        printf "%s\n" "$l2"
     fi
done 3< fisier.txt 4< fisier1.txt
```

You could handle a different count of lines too. I have this (rather verbose) idea:

```
while true; do

    IFS= read -r -u3 l1
    l1valid=$?
    IFS= read -r -u4 l2
    l2valid=$?
    if ((l1valid != 0 || l2valid != 0)); then
        if ((l1valid != 0 && l2valid == 0)); then
           echo "file1 is longer then file2"
        elif ((l1valid == 0 && l2valid != 0)); then
           echo "file1 is shorter then file2"
        fi # l1valid != 0 && l2valid != 0 - all fine
        break;
    fi

    if [ "$l1" != "$l2" ]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$l1"
        printf "%s\n" "$l2"
     fi

done 3< fisier.txt 4< fisier1.txt
```

or like:

```
while
    IFS= read -r -u3 l1
    l1valid=$?
    IFS= read -r -u4 l2
    l2valid=$?
    if ((l1valid != 0 && l2valid == 0)); then
       echo "file1 is longer then file2"
    elif ((l1valid == 0 && l2valid != 0)); then
       echo "file1 is shorter then file2"
    fi
    (( l1valid == 0 && l2valid == 0 ))
do
    if [ "$l1" != "$l2" ]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$l1"
        printf "%s\n" "$l2"
     fi
done 3< fisier.txt 4< fisier1.txt
```

Note that bash loops are very slow, it will be magnitudes faster with awk:

```
awk -vother="fisier1.txt" '{ t=$0; getline < (other); if (t != $0) print $0 RS t }' fisier.txt
```

Comment: But how can i do, instead of the second while, just to have an if that reads the line from the second file, 'cause i do not need all differences, i only need the differences between lines with the same  "line index". Line 1 from file 1, with line 1 from file 2...line 2 from file 1,with line 2 from file 2...etc.?

Comment: In this case the `fisier1.txt` will be opened every time when the new line read from the file `fisier.txt`. And each line from the first file will be compared with each line from the second one. I am not sure it's what TS wants.

Comment: Insanely cool! You invented a light version of the `diff`/`comm` tools in pure shell.

Comment: That method with awk works perfectly! Thanks a lot! But can u explain me why when i put your code into my shell, i become the error "syntax error near unexpected token `3' "?

Comment: Arg too many spaces. Fixed. There needs to be no space between file descriptor number and `<` or `>` character.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what do you want exactly:

1. do you need 5 different lines from both files
2. do you need 5 different lines from each file

The following examples are not the latest solutions, but the food for the further thoughts

The solution for the first case -- take differences only and print first 5 lines:

```
comm -3 FILE1 FILE2 | head -n5
```

The solution for the second case -- take differences only and print 5 different lines from each file (10 lines in total):

```
comm -3 FILE1 FILE2 | head -n10
```

Updated:

The examples above were suggested in the assumption that both `FILE1` and `FILE2` are sorted. If they are not sorted you need to enhance both examples as follows:

```
comm -3 <( sort FILE1 ) <( sort FILE2 ) | ...
```

Notes:

1. The rest of commands (the ellipsis after the pipe) is the same.
2. This is BASH way

Comment: This is not going to help me, cause my files are not sorted. They contain words on each line. I need to compare line 1 from file 1 with line 1 from file 2 and if they are different, then i will display line 1 from file 1 and line 1 from file 2, if they are equal i will go to the next line. I should do this thing until i have 5 displayed lines.

Comment: I have updated my answer while you commented. Please read the updated version of the answer. Updates reflect to the sorting issue only.